# Tkinter GUI is not opening after adding image to GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

My Tkinter GUI works fine if I commented out the last 4 lines of my code above mainloop(). I want to add the image. If I included the lines then the code runs without giving any error but its not displaying GUI. What could be the problem in adding image (I have tried all .jpg, .png, .gif)? [image: This is my GUI]

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def show_answer():
    Ans = (float(num1.get())**2)-(((float(num1.get()) - float(num2.get()))**2)/2)
    blank.insert(0, Ans)


main = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(main, text = "The Area of pseodo square:").grid(row=2)


num1 = tk.Entry(main)
num2 = tk.Entry(main)
blank = tk.Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank.grid(row=2, column=1)


tk.Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.destroy).grid(row=4, column=0, pady=4)
tk.Button(main, text='Calculate', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=4)

##img = "download.png"
##photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img))
##panel = tk.Label(main, image = photo)
##panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your setup. This gives a very descriptive error on my machine: *_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `grid` and `pack`. Use only one geometry manager for a parent widget:

For example, use `grid` for the image label.

```
img = "download.png"
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img))
panel = tk.Label(main, image = photo)
panel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)  # <---
```

[image]